# Getting Wrong Output in TestNG

Tags: testng

Please check the below code, i am executing this particular code, but getting output as 
    Got URL
    Testing Scenario
    Logged Out
    Logged In.

```
But as per priority given output should be different. 
Kindly look into it and help me on this.

public class DependencyAnnotation {
    @Test(groups={"PreCondition"},priority=0)
    public void getURL(){
        System.out.println("Got URL");
    }

    @Test(priority=1,dependsOnGroups={"PreCondition"})
    public void login() {
        System.out.println("Logged In");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void testScenario(){
        System.out.println("Testing Scenario");
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void logout(){
        System.out.println("Logged Out");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getURL()` and `login()` form a chain of dependency; `testScenario()` and `logout()` don't. 
[They fall into different schedules](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors)

Apparently, priorities are applied within the scope of each group.

So, this layout does not do what you expect.

As a palliative, try making `testScenario()` and `logout()` depend on `getURL()` too.

Also please consider using models involving methods annontated with `@Before*` and `@After*`.